# In a single query i want to get data from two different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get data from two tables in my DB. Here's what my tables might look like:

```
subject_code:  semester, subjectcode, subjectname
markmanagment: subjectcode, semester, marks, rollno
```

i want to select rollno value=1 and semester value=1 and its corresponding values of marks and subject code from table markmanagment and for the same value of semester and subject code i want the subjectname from subject_code

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic join. Use an INNER JOIN to see only the results that have records in both tables - I used the subject code in the ON statement but you could also use semester here. Then specify your other conditions in the WHERE clause. In your SELECT statement, specify the columns you want to see returned by listing them in the following format: tablename.columnname. I use * here to return all columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM subject_code sc
INNER JOIN markmanagement mm ON sc.subjectcode = mm.subjectcode
WHERE sc.semester = mm.semester
AND sc.semester = 1
AND mm.rollno = 1
```

Comment: after executed your query by using result set rs.next()in a while loop i printed marks by using system.out.print it havent printed anything

Comment: Your question just asked about the query. The one above is correct given the information we have, and so are several other queries on the page. If there is other information that we need to answer the question, you'll have to let us know. You didn't mention anything about a while loop

Answer (score 0):

You should do a join table (Inner - Right - Left or Full, depending on your table).

Like :

```
SELECT * FROM subject_code
INNER JOIN markmanagment
ON subject_code.subjectcode = markmanagment.subjectcode; 
WHERE markmanagment.rollno = 1 AND subject_code.semester = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple conditions in the `on` part of a join. For example:

```
select  *
from    markmanagement mm
join    subject_code sc
on      mm.subjectcode = sc.subjectcode
        and mm.semester = sc.semester
where   mm.semester = 1
        and mm.rollno = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, i understood your problem correctly.

Tried to create same problem.

Sqlfiddle link - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a074b/2/0

```
create table subject_code
(
semester int,
subjectcode varchar(100),
subjectname varchar(100)
);

insert into subject_code values(1,'S01','subject1');
insert into subject_code values(1,'S02','subject2');
insert into subject_code values(2,'S01','subject1');

create table markmanagment
(
  subjectcode varchar(100),
  semester int,
  marks int ,
  rollno int
);

insert into markmanagment values('S01',1,75,1);
insert into markmanagment values('S02',1,80,1);
insert into markmanagment values('S01',2,85,1);
```

I think below query will help

```
select b.marks , b.subjectcode , a.subjectname 
from subject_code a, markmanagment b
where a.semester = b.semester
and a.subjectcode = b.subjectcode
and a.semester = 1
and b.rollno = 1;
```